# Generating grammar from a string

Tags: graph-algorithms, fl.formal-languages, pl.programming-languages, grammars, compilers

Given a string generated with a valid grammar, how can I find list of all the valid grammar for that particular string?

Problem statement - I'm trying to build a code base scanner, and I'd like to build it independent of language such as javascript / typescript. Instead of writing the grammar rules my self, I wanted to try a challenge of building something that can generate the grammar out of it.

Comment: Two comments. First, you certainly do not want *all* grammars, because that's too many. Second, do you real mean to say that you have a *single* example? If you can provide *many* examples, then there ought to be machine-learning tools.

Comment: If you want to challenge yourself, why not participate in our (regular) grammar induction challenge [https://codalab.lisn.upsaclay.fr/competitions/15096](https://codalab.lisn.upsaclay.fr/competitions/15096). It's remarkably easy to get started, a basic solution can be written in a few lines of code (although it won't perform well on larger examples). Associated paper: [https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.07899](https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.07899). (The overall aim of this work quantification of learning algorithms for programs.)

Comment: Note that grammar induction is one of the oldest fields in machine learning, going back, at least,  to Gold's 1960s work on  [*Language identification in the limit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_identification_in_the_limit).

Comment: @MartinBerger thanks for the invite. I'm interested ! Rather than writing a script that runs on large code base, I want to build an interface where the logic can be created dynamically and run indefinitely. Looks to me that both this question and that challenge are the same!

Comment: @AndrejBauer I'm trying some ideas for code base size reduction. Generating all the grammar will be redundant, so I'll be throwing up the patterns on an infinite 2d space where I can build interaction to mark a valid grammar, reject / ignore an existing grammar. In other words it is a sub graph detection as well, and idea is to figure out a technique to define a sub graph and let the background script detect such patterns.

Comment: I have had a little progress on this, instead of solving this problem, I tried to solve how to trace the control flow and data flow in a code base. I have been running in circles, and I realised, if I trace the source of a data from a leaf, the problem is sovled, in the sense, If I click on a variable, the tracer will trace back code in reverse to find where it imported its data from.

Comment: @MartinBerger the place has too much information there and mis direct me. In my opinion, input+function = output is conventional programming. input+output = function is machine learning. so the technique is irrelevant because solving problem then applying the technique will result in a simple solution.

Comment: @Vetrivel I don't understand what you mean by *"place has too much information there and mis direct me"*. Our challenge is *exactly* about building grammars (in this case regular grammars) from example strings.

Comment: @MartinBerger I meant to say, It took me some years to adjust with stackoverflow interface. and I'm finding it difficult to read information because of the visual interface.

Comment: @Martinberger I solved the problem I wanted to solve in a different way. Instead of reducing code base size alternatively if I trace the data source or the data flow in reverse I can fetch all the lines at different time of order of execution. That was just a piece of a bigger problem

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in [Sequitur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequitur_algorithm) (given a single string, it compresses it by finding a grammar that generates just that one string) or in [grammar induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar_induction) (given a set of strings, it finds a grammar that can generate all of those strings).
See

- [What is the current state of the art in black-box grammar induction?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/41926/5038),
- https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/64556/755,
- https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/53279/755.